# Tradução de "bleeding heart" -- "coração mole"?

Tags: tradução-inglês

Parece que há certa ironia na expressão em inglês, veja:

http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=bleeding%20heart

A expressão em português não é um anglicismo e parece ter a mesma conotação:

http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/cora%C3%A7%C3%A3o%20mole/

O uso é no contexto de "bleeding-heart libertarianism".

Comment: O que exatamente você quer saber? Se as duas expressões têm o mesmo significado, ou se uma veio de outra e/ou vice-versa? Poderia elaborar um pouco mais a sua pergunta?

Comment: Engraçado, por que o "libertarianismo" é sem dúvida a posição política de coração mais duro que eu conheço (e, sim, estou levando o fascismo em consideração ao escrever isso).

Comment: @Luís Foi isso também que eu pensei, mas há de facto um chamado [bleeding heart libertarianism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bleeding-heart_libertarianism). Parece que é um movimento heterogéneo, mas inclui uma corrente que está disposta a deixar cair aspetos do libertarianismo puro e duro se isso for necessário para conseguir o bem-estar dos mais desfavorecidos.

Comment: Felipe, o problema que eu vejo nesta pergunta é que ela é mais sobre o significado de *bleeding heart* e *bleeding-heart libertarianism* que de *coração mole*, sobre o qual não há grandes dúvidas. Ora o foco das perguntas deve ser a língua portuguesa. Mesmo nas perguntas de tradução, quem pergunta deve clarificar o significado da expressão a traduzir, e o trabalho de quem responde deve ser apenas encontrar e analisar uma expressão correspondente em português. Vê [esta discussão no meta](http://meta.portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/263/pode-se-pedir-tradu%C3%A7%C3%B5es-para-alem%C3%A3o).

Comment: Bleeding heart se junta com qualquer substantivo. Se usa muito em política. O mais conhecido é: bleeding heart liberal. Mas qualquer pessoa que exagera demais em qualquer assunto de tipo politico pode se um bleeding heart + substantivo: liberal, libertarian, socialist, environmentalist etc. Sim coração mole.

Comment: Felipe, deves incluir na pergunta a definição do termo original, ou uma explicação do que ele significa, para te podermos ajudar adequadamente. Idealmente incluis também um par de frases-exemplo, em que podemos ver o uso da palavra e de onde podemos tirar melhor o contexto.